AWS Athena/Glue always 'rounds down' Parquet timestamp microseconds to milliseconds
I'm using an AWS S3 Parquet data lake, mapped via Glue and then queried via Amazon Athena. My timestamps are in microseconds. The problem is that Athena/Glue maps this to milliseconds, in a way where it always 'rounds down' to the nearest millisecond, instead of rounding up/down.
For example, 2024-04-16 08:37:24.500550 becomes 2024-04-16 08:37:24.500 - while the expected result would be that it becomes 2024-04-16 08:37:24.501.
I need the Parquet files at full microsecond resolution as the data lake is also analyzed through other tools that are not restricted to milliseconds - so I do not want to round the timestamps to milliseconds during the write process.
Is there a way to solve this in e.g. the mapping process of Glue - and is this rounding a 'known bug' for AWS Glue/Athena?

Unfortunately there isn't a way to control the rounding of the timestamps right now (maybe try submitting a feature request for the future?).
Is it possible to store the data as string/VARCHAR instead of TIMESTAMP in your Parquet file? That workaround should be able to keep the microsecond precision you need
Let me know if this helped
